# Smart tricks used to prove formulas by approximation

Tags: analysis, big-list, approximation-theory

I've recently seen a proof of the inversion formula for the Fourier transform for $f,\hat{f}\in L^1(\mathbb{R}^d)$.
The main idea of the proof is this

> We have 
>   $$\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}e^{2\pi i x\cdot \xi}\hat f(\xi)d\xi=\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}e^{2\pi i x\cdot \xi}\left(\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}e^{-2 \pi i y\cdot \xi}dy\right)d\xi.$$ But at this point Fubini doesn't apply thus we can't change the two integrals.
>   Nevertheless, here is the trick (which I find really smart) for $t>0$ we consider this modified version of the integral 
>   $$I_t(x):=\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}\hat f(\xi)e^{-\pi t^2\vert\xi\vert^2}e^{2\pi i x\cdot\xi}d\xi.$$
>   Now we can use Fubini and compute the integral in two ways and for $t\rightarrow0$ we get the result. By the way everything works because the damping factor is an eigenvector of the Fourier transform of eigenvalue 1 (so it is far from being a random choice).

I was astonished by the proof, we considered an apparently more complicated expression which allowed us to use a particular property and then passed to the limit and obtained the result.
My question is: what are other examples of the same idea?
I know that basically anything which involves approximation with smooth functions falls in this class but I'm asking for some particular example/application (of this or a similar idea) that made you think '**cool**'.
(details are welcome).

Answer (score 1):

Computing [real integrals via complex contour integration](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1300055/integrals-on-the-real-line-using-contour-integration) and limits [seems to fit exactly](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/135917/calculating-a-real-integral-using-complex-integration).

This also happens in discrete mathematics: I recently came to [a combinatorial proof of the identity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2731637/is-the-numerator-of-sum-k-0n-1k-binomnk-frac12k1-always-a/2731675#2731675) $$
\sum_{k=0}^{n}{(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}\frac{1}{2k+1}}={(2n)!!\over  (2n+1)!!}
$$
where the key is to consider the properties of $\sum_{k=0}^{n}{(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}\frac{1}{2k+m}}$ for arbitrary values of $m$.

Comment: I've never studied complex integration, but now I'm intrigued and I will take a look at your links (tomorrow)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_proof

Comment: @adfriedman Not sure I see your point. Are you trying to imply that *The term "combinatorial proof" may also be used more broadly to refer to any kind of elementary proof in combinatorics.* should appear in boldface so that people don't miss it?